# How do I sort NSArrays by objects inside the objects inside the NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Think Inception. Say I have 2 objects `A` and `B` and each instance of `A` has a variable `B` and each `B` has an `NSNumber` variable.

I have an NSArray `Array` with instances of `A` inside it and I want to sort it based on the `NSNumber` variable within B. So the normal approach of going

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,nil];

NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"b" ascending: YES];
array = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]];
```

just isn't going to cut it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting should work fine with this approach as long as you use the proper key for comparison as follows:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,nil];

NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"b.nsnumbervar" ascending: YES];
array = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortOrder]];
```

Comment: Wait, it doesn't work :\

Comment: The property key for sort descriptor needs to be accessed using key-value coding

Comment: Wait, sorry, I think my code is faulty. I'll check back in a bit :)

Comment: A key path is a string of dot separated keys that is used to specify a sequence of object properties to traverse. The property of the first key in the sequence is relative to the receiver, and each subsequent key is evaluated relative to the value of the previous property.

For example, the key path address.street would get the value of the address property from the receiving object, and then determine the street property relative to the address object.

Comment: Yeah, okay, it worked. My code really was just faulty. Thank you :)